# Possible to test Google social login locally?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I want to test the Google Social login system on my local machine. However when I create a new OAuth button: 'Create New Client ID' it requires me to fill in the Authorized redirect URI which needs to be a valid address (ends with .com or .org).

Obviously when we develop locally we don't have the .com or .org at the end. I have a virtualhost setup... and my address to my local development is mywebsite.local

Is there a way to input the redirect URI to be `mywebsite.local` without receinv the error:

> Invalid Redirect: http://mywebsite.local/login/auth must end with a
>   public top-level domain (such as .com or .org)

Comment: What about cloud? I'm running jenkins on Azure and I got ip address

Answer (score 11):

You can set "Authorized redirect URI" to local IP (like http://127.0.0.1/callback), it's working fine for me.

What really agonizing is that google don't allow user to config an external IP (let's say your server IP like 99.99.99.99) as "Authorized redirect URI", google want the "Authorized redirect URI" to end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org).

Comment: I can't find the field "Authorized redirect URI" on **APIs & Services > Credentials > OAuth consent screen** maybe they changed the UI or removed that feature

Comment: It's under "Authorized domains"

Answer (score 9):

Further to pinoyyid's answer, here's what you'd want in your `/etc/hosts` file.

```
0.0.0.0 mywebsite.com
```

I put new rules after everything else that's already in there.

you can then access your development site at mywebsite.com and enter the correct redirect URL in the Google Developer's Console.

Answer (score 4):

I made a simple tool for this exact purpose.

Just set your redirect URL to http://redirectmeto.com/http://mywebsite.local/login/auth

Answer (score 3):

Just map your dev server IP address to dev.example.com in your /etc/hosts.

Comment: It does provide an answer. The issue is that the Google form validates that the user has input a valid looking URL. So he needs to input an arbitrary, but valid URL, and then add that to /etc/hosts so his browser will resolve it to the address of his devserver. The question and answer are both fine as is and don't require any critique or clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can ngrok to tunnel your localhost into public site, as described [here](https://medium.com/@Madgeek_in/oauth-2-testing-on-localhost-with-https-ssl-f3aa3655f089).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you have to use localhost or url with public top level domain (I use .bar) and all redirect urls have to be https (in case you want to have verified google app - needed for sheets/drive api)

Answer (score 0):

Steps will help for windows users:

1. Go to host file which should be C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
2. Create add entry in host file like
   127.0.0.1       localhost.com
3. Save it. User localhost.com as a organization in google dev console.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The key is to use an `https` URL on your local environment.

On OSX you can install local https certificate: https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

Or use Laravel Valet.

So, your new localhost URL becomes: `https://mywebsite.local`

Then save this `https` callback on google. Works on my computer